# How to increment a counter with only an object of a class/function without calling any of the function's methods or properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, closures, javascript-objects

In the code below,

`let increment = new Increment();`

I am to write a class/function `Increment` in Javascript such that

`` console.log(`${increment}`) `` // the output is 1

`` console.log(`${increment}`) ``; // the output is 2

`` console.log(`${increment}`) ``; // the output is 3

`` console.log(`${increment}`) ``; // the output is 4

`increment` cannot be a function i.e I cannot do `increment()` or it cannot to a property for the purpose i.e. I cannot do `increment.count`

So, the whole question looks like this,

```
let increment = new Increment();

console.log(`${increment}`); //1

console.log(`${increment}`); //2

console.log(`${increment}`); //3

console.log(`${increment}`); //4
```

and I am supposed to implement a function `Increment` to get the expected output.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a class with a private field and overwrite `toString()` method so that it increments and returns that private field, try:

```js
class Increment{
    constructor(){
       this.i = 1;
    }
    
    toString(){
        return this.i++;
    }
}

let increment = new Increment();

console.log(`${increment}`);

console.log(`${increment}`);

console.log(`${increment}`);

console.log(`${increment}`);
```

Similar approach with function:

```js
function Increment(){
    let i = 1;
    return { toString: () => i++ }
}

let increment = new Increment();

console.log(`${increment}`);

console.log(`${increment}`);

console.log(`${increment}`);

console.log(`${increment}`);
```